# How does this integration by parts work: $\int_{Q}v\varphi_t\;dxdt = -\int_S \varphi v|_{S} \nu_t - \int_Q v_t \varphi\;dxdt$

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, surfaces

> Let $\Omega(t)$ be a bounded domain for each $t$. Let $Q=\bigcup_{t \in [0,T]} \Omega(t) \times \{t\}$ and $S=\bigcup_{t \in [0,T]} \partial\Omega(t) \times \{t\}$.
>
> The normal vector to $S$ at $(x,t)$ is $\nu = (\nu_x, \nu_t)$.
>
> We have by integration by parts
> $$\int_{Q}v\varphi_t\;dxdt = -\int_S \varphi v|_{S} \nu_t - \int_Q v_t \varphi\;dxdt$$

I don't understand how the integration in parts is done here.  Since we are just integrating over time, which is 1D, why don't we just get a term which is a difference between $t=T$ and $t=0$? What is the integration by parts formula used here?

Comment: look at [Stoke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem).

Comment: Thanks but it is very abstract there..